# How to detect when a new item version is added in an event receiver?

Tags: 2010, development, event-receivers, itemupdated

Is there a way to detect (in C#) if a new item version was added in either `ItemAdded` or `ItemUpdated` event? I would only like to execute some code when either new item is added, or a new version of the item is added.

Event `ItemAdded` only fires when a totally new item is added. However, it doesn't fire when new versions of the same item are added; instead, `ItemUpdated` fires in this case. But `ItemUpdated` can be triggered multiple times by various events, not just when a new item version is added and there doesn't seem to be a property that would indicate the creation of new item version.

Comment: Whenever an item is updated a version is created. The version may be major or minor. Do you want to run your custom code only when a major version is created?

Comment: @NadeemYousuf I want to run the code when either a major or minor version is created. While it is true that if versioning is enabled, any update will create a new version, it is also true that `ItemUpdated` can get called for reasons other than new version creation (see e.g. [ItemUpdated Events Firing Twice](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/)).

Answer (score 1):

In the ItemUpdating ER the value properties.AfterProperties["vti_contenttag"] is null when the doc is added, overwritting another one.

This could be a way to go, not the best for sure, but still a working solution

Comment: This doesn't seem to always be the case and doesn't seem reliable. For example, if I edit the description of a document without checking it in, nothing new is added or overwritten (no version is created), yet vti_contenttag is null.

Comment: You can also check the checkout status of the file. As this is only a workaround because there is no direct solution for thsi.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Sharepoint designer?  As far as I see it, you have two options you can do here.

1. If you want to try, you can create your own custom sharepoint actions.  This can be done in any IDE environment.  You could modify ItemAdded to only look for unique GUIDs to the list or something.
2. I'm pretty sure the GUID variable in sharepoint is for unique elements?  If not, and I'm being stupid, then you could create a new variable to store a unique ID for a variable, so that in a workflow you could check for a new ID, and only fire ItemUpdated of Added based on this new variable.

Comment: I'm not using the designer unfortunately. The problem with GUIDs is that all item versions have the same GUID (even at database table level), so creating my own action would likely be a pretty painful experience.

Comment: My best option would be to create a new field in your database then to hold your own ID variable to track what you want.  Then use CAML queries to check if the ID of the new item is the same as another element (It is just a new version), or if there are no matching ID's (brand new element).  Just know that if you have a lot of elements, these will be cumbersome queries.

Comment: This seems like too much overhead in which case I'd rather pursue an alternative solution to my original problem (not discussed in the question). Besides, as far as I know, there's no need to create a new field: item versions can be obtained from `AllDocsStreams` and `AllDocsVersions` tables in the database - however, querying the database directly is normally not recommended and this method would likely introduce potential synchronization issues. Not worth it for the task I'm trying to accomplish. :)

Comment: Yeah, if you want to add functionality not specifically stated by Sharepoint, it can be a pretty big hassel.  Best of luck to you!